# Taylor expansion of the flow of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a manifold, $X$ be a vector field on $\mathcal{M}$ and $p\in\mathcal{M}$. Let $\sigma(\epsilon,p)$ be the flow of $X$ at $p$. Performing a Taylor expansion about $\epsilon = 0$ we get
$$ \sigma^{\mu}(\epsilon,p) = x^{\mu}(p) + \epsilon X^{\mu}(p) + O(\epsilon^{2}) $$

Whilst I understand the Taylor expansion itself, when I go to apply this to an example I don't get equality. For example, if we let $\mathcal{M}=\mathbb{R}$, $p\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, then $$\gamma :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},$$ 
$$t\mapsto t+p$$ is an integral curve of $X$ at $p$. So the flow of $X$ at $p$ is given by 
$$\sigma(\epsilon,p) = \epsilon + p$$ But the right hand side of the Taylor expansion gives
$$ p + \epsilon\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\mid_{p} + O(\epsilon^{2}) $$
Now I realise that this is almost certainly a problem with my understanding of one the concepts involved here so can someone explain to me which part I am getting wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $X$ is a vector field, then for fixed $\mu$, $X^\mu$ is a smooth function so $X^\mu(p)$ is a number, not a vector. Also do you know what that big O notation means?

Comment: Ok so is the $X^{\mu}$ the coefficient in front of the basis expansion $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$? So maybe in a better example than the on I gave, if $X = x^{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}} - x^{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}$ is a vector field over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, would this give $X^{1} = x^{1}$ and $X^{2} = -x^{2}$?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Ok thank you I think thats where I was going wrong as I thought that $X^{\mu}(p) = X^{\mu}_{p}$ but now this is making more sense.

Comment: Great, do you understand what the $O(\epsilon^2)$ means?

Comment: I think I have a rough idea of what it means: doesn't it mean any terms in the expansion which grow at a rate less than or equal to the rate of $\epsilon^{2}$?

Comment: Yes that's roughly what it means. More precisely, if $f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to \infty$, then there are $M$ and $x_0$ such that for all $x \geq x_0$ we have $\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq M \lvert g(x) \rvert$.